# What is the flow to Create an application in Azure app directory to automate onenote?

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api, onenote-api

I have registered an app in the Azure active drirectory for using graph api for the one note automation.

My question is the app registration what value I should give for redirect uri, to automate onenote.

Can someone summarise the next steps to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

The redirect URI just needs to be where you want your users directed to after they are authenticated and have been granted access to your app. There is an example in [this guide](https://gist.github.com/nandini-menon/0b10c1276db767bc0f1af2cfc8aece5b) of what to set as the Redirect URI for automating creation of OneNote notebooks. Here they use:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{azure_active_directory_id}/oauth2/token
```

Comment: Thanks for confirming! Feel free to accept it if it resolved the issue. :)